# Chess Board - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

In how many ways you can put three rooks on a chessboard so that no two of them are in same row ,column or diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OEIS A047659 "Number of ways to place 3 nonattacking queens on an n X n board."

http://oeis.org/A047659

Comment: queen != rook (:

Comment: @Douglas, that's as may be, but look at the original question, which asks the rooks not be on the same diagonal. For this problem, those rooks have been promoted to queens!

Comment: Oops!  You're right.

Comment: :) Thanks, Gerry, for pointing it out.